# What is the fastest way to check whether all 'Seq' elements are of size 1 in a Scala Set?

Tags: scala

This is what I am doing right now:

```
val foo = Set[Seq[Int]](Seq(1), Seq(2), Seq(3))
val isAllSizeOne = foo.foldLeft(true) { case (agg, curr) => agg && curr.size == 1}
```

Can I get any faster than this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most concise version:

```
val isAllSizeOne = foo.forall(_.size == 1)
```

Another alternative that **might** be faster but is less concise:

```
val isAllSizeOne = foo.forall(_.lengthCompare(1) == 0)
```

Comment: In particular, `lengthCompare` is fast for sequences that don't know their own size like `List` since it can bail out early instead of counting everything if it finds more than one element.  For sequences that do know their own length, it requires additional logic that one hopes the JVM will eventually optimize away.  (Usually does in my experience, at least in heavily-used code paths which are the ones I care about.)

Answer (score 9):

The method `forall` is designed to do exactly what you ask.

```
foo.forall(_.size == 1)
```

In most cases it will be the fastest implementation you can find.  As always, if it's very important you should try to benchmark and/or profile the alternatives, and be aware that which is fastest may depend on which collection you're using.

Answer (score 4):

For very large collections, worth considering also a parallelised version using `par`, for instance like this,

```
foo.par.forall(_.size == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Size operation requires to loop through all the elements in sequence, another alternative might be:

```
foo.forall(l => l.nonEmpty && l.tail.isEmpty)
```

Although considering size of the Sequence is small, it does not make much difference.

Comment: Bad idea!  `tail`, for most `Seq`s (save list, which admittedly is the default implementation), will create a new collection!  If it is immutable it may be not terribly expensive, but it will certainly be more expensive than counting elements.  You should only do this if you're _really sure_ your `tail` operation is inexpensive (e.g. you are `LinearSeqLike`).